# Find source file with R package "reticulate"

Tags: r, directory, multilingual, reticulate

I'm working on an `R` project with several folders. The working directory is where the main script and a folder called `src` are located. That folder contains two `python` scripts, one called `test_function.py` and the other called `test_script.py`.

I'm using the `reticulate` package in the main script and I tried to use the function `source_python( )` to call the `python` scripts. Code looks like this:

```
# Main R script
library(reticulate)
source_python("test_function.py")
```

However, I get the following error

> Error in py_run_file_impl(file, local, convert) : 
>     Unable to open file 'test_func.py' (does it exist?)

Now, the working directory looks something like this:

```
setwd("C:/Users/.../testProject")
```

And the function `source_python( )` only works when I move to where the python script is located

```
setwd("C:/Users/.../testProject/src")
```

Yet I need to make it work from the directory where the main `R` script is located, because the `R` project will be quite complex and will require multiple sources (some of which will written in `python`)

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Can you not do `source_python("./src/test_function.py")`?

Comment: I tried that but sadly it didn't work. Error is the same `Error in py_run_file_impl(file, local, convert) : Unable to open file './src/test_func.py' (does it exist?)`

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `scriptName` package.  Example:

Script file "~/Desktop/temp.r":

```
library(scriptName)
library(reticulate)
x <- scriptName::current_filename()
print(dirname(x))
source_python(paste0(dirname(x), "/src/test_function.py"))
```

`source("~/Desktop/temp.r")` Output:

```
[1] "script path is: "
[1] "/Users/thc/Desktop"
```

Comment: I have never heard of the `scriptName` package. I tried using it, but `x` turns out to be `Null` and hence `print(dirnam(x))` returns `Error in dirname(x) : a character vector argument expected`. Can you help me with that? It seems that the problem is with `x`. As stated above, my working directory is something like `C:/Users/.../testProject` and the python script is in `C:/Users/.../testProject/src`

Comment: You also seem to call the main script at the end, but I can't figure out why if I'm already working on that script.

Comment: If you just copy and paste the code into a console in rstudio, it is just from clipboard, not from the file.  You need to call the script itself e.g. with `source` or with `Rscript`, you can't work interactively.

Comment: The line at the end `source("~/Desktop/temp.r")` is how you would call the script, not part of the script.